# Graphviz: pre-set nodes in a regular shape

Tags: graphviz

I have 10 nodes that are all connected to each other and I am trying to generate a graph using   `neato`. I set `graph [overlap=false]` and my output is currently in the general shape of an octagon with two nodes stuck in the middle.

What I want is for the nodes to be arranged as a decagon along the outside of the graph with no nodes stuck in the middle. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: try the "circo" layout

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "[circo](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/circo.1.pdf)" layout should help to obtain the required outcome.